# Web worker must collect data and send it to a node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker

I am new in JS and I have a task to implement the functionality to send user click events (clicks on buttons, the email input field) to a web worker. The worker must collect data into the batches of 5 items and send it to the server (using POST /analytics/user) endpoint. The problem is that I don't understand how to collect user clicks and send them into batches of 5 items which I searched for documentation but nowhere is mentioned about batches. Could you help me please?  My website has 3 buttons,2 of them doesn't have any event listeners and the last one is used to submit an email, as shown below:
[image]

**/analytics/user endpoint code from route:**

```
 router.post('/user', async function (req, res) {
  const payload = req.body;
  try {
    let data;
    try {
      data = await FileStorage.readJsonFile('user-analytics.json');
    } catch (e) {
      data = [];
    }

    data.push({timestamp: Date.now(), data: payload});
    await FileStorage.writeFile('user-analytics.json', data);
    await res.json({success: true})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Internal error');
  }
});
```

Let me know if I should add more information about something.

Edit :
I wrote the functions to send button clicks and after that the worker should send the data to server, but now the problem is that I can not push messages to web worker to an array ,it pushes only first message..

Function for sending user clicks to the web worker :

```
  export const sendUserClicksToWorker = () => {
    const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("app-section__button");
    const inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("form-input")
    let reason = [];
    //for loop for pushing clicks from buttonts to the array
    for (let x = 0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
        allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
            worker.postMessage(this.textContent)
            console.log(this.textContent)
        });
    }
    //for loop for pushing click from email input field to the array
    for (let x = 0; x < inputField.length; x++) {
        inputField[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
            worker.postMessage(this.textContent)
            console.log(this.textContent)
        });
    }
    
}
```

Function for sending data to the server :

```
export const sendButtonClicksToServer = (dataToSend) => {
    sendHttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/analytics/user', {
        dataToSend
    }).then(responseData => {
        return responseData
        //console.log(responseData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err, err.data)
        window.alert(err.data.error)
    })
}
```

And in main js file :

```
 if (window.Worker) {
      const url = new URL('./scripts/worker.js', import.meta.url);
      const worker = new Worker(url);
      
      const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("app-section__button");
      const inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("form-input")
      //for loop for pushing clicks from buttonts to the array
      for (let x = 0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
          allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
              worker.postMessage(this.textContent)
              //console.log(this.textContent)
          });
      }
      //for loop for pushing click from email input field to the array
      for (let x = 0; x < inputField.length; x++) {
          inputField[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
              worker.postMessage(this.textContent)
             // console.log(this.textContent)
          });
      }

      worker.onmessage = e => {
        console.log(e.data)
        sendButtonClicksToServer(e.data);
      }
      worker.onerror = error => {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
    }
```

And worker.js :

```
let data = []
onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Data Received: ',e.data)

let receivedButtonClicks = e.data
// data.push(receivedButtonClicks)
// if (data.length > 4) {
//     postMessage(data)
//     data.length = 0;
//     console.log('Data received!')
//     console.log(data)
// }
for ( let i = 0 ; i< 5;i++){
    data[i].push(receivedButtonClicks)
}



console.log('blabla',data)
}
```

Now I don't understand 100% where is the problem and how to fix it??..

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you allowed to do this without using a worker?

Comment: Yes,it is and i should do with a web worker..  4 hours already i try to push messages that come to webworker in an array and all what i get is an array of 5 similar items :(

Comment: Part of the issue is you are declaring `data` inside your `onmessage` function, which is creating a new, empty list every time a message is received. Try putting it above `onmessage` (in the global scope) and see how much that fixes

Comment: I declared it above and has the same problem :(

Comment: Can you edit your question with the updated code? I am surprised that it didn't fix the issue

Comment: I posted the fresh code

Comment: You want to write `data.push(...)`, not `data[i].push(...)` -- `data[i]` is referencing elements of `data` that don't exist. Also I would rename `data` to `batch` or something like that, just for sanity. Better variable names will keep the meaning of the variables more clear and help you write your own code.

Comment: So,i have put in the for loop the condition that i<1 and removed [i[ from batch and now it creates the array like it should do,thank you .Now remains to make it to send the array to the server when its fullfilled with 5 items and renew the array again and again

Comment: Oh yes.now i did everything,thank you for help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,i managed how to do this task and i came back here showing my functionality :

I did two functions,one for sending user clicks to the webworker in the following way :

```
const sendUserClicksToWorker = () => {
    if (window.Worker) {
        const url = new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url);
        const worker = new Worker(url);

        const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("app-section__button");
        const inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("form-input")

        //for loop for pushing clicks from buttonts to the array
        for (let x = 0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
            allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
                worker.postMessage(this.textContent)
            });
        }
        //for loop for pushing click from email input field to the array
        for (let x = 0; x < inputField.length; x++) {
            inputField[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
                worker.postMessage(this.textContent)
            });
        }

        worker.onmessage = e => {
           // console.log('Thread received data: ', e.data)
            sendButtonClicksToServer(e.data);
        }
        worker.onerror = error => {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }

}
```

On every button click it posts a message to the webworker. And the second function for sending data to the server:

```
const sendButtonClicksToServer = (dataToSend) => {
    sendHttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/analytics/user', {
        dataToSend
    }).then(responseData => {
        return responseData
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err, err.data)
        window.alert(err.data.error)
    })
}
```

The webworker procces the data received this way and sends back to the main thread were on next step,it is being send to the server:

```
let batch = []
onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Data Received: ',e.data)
    let receivedButtonClicks = e.data

for ( let i = 0 ; i< 1;i++){
    batch.push(receivedButtonClicks)

    if (batch.length > 4){
        postMessage(batch)
        batch.length = 0
        console.log('Data was sent!')
    }
}

}
```

It wasnt that hard,but it took damn too much time. Thanks everyone for help!